# How to create emptyRDD using SparkSession - (since hivecontext got deprecated)

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-2.2

IN Spark version 1.*

Created emptyRDD like below:

```
var baseDF = hiveContextVar.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], baseSchema)
```

While migrating to Spark 2.0(since hiveContext got deprecated, using sparkSession)

Tried like:

```
var baseDF = sparkSession.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], baseSchema)
```

Though getting below error:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running
>   in this JVM (see SPARK-2243)

Is there a way to create emptyRDD using sparkSession?

Comment: That's not what causing the error. Something else in your code is !

Comment: It seems you try to use two spark contexts (sparkSession and sc) which is why you get an error.

Comment: Indeed @Shaido the OP is ofc falling in the lazy computation trap but for the time being, the code posted doesn't cause the error given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spark 2.0 you need to refer the spark context through spark session. You can create empty dataframe as below. It worked for me.

sparkSession.createDataFrame(sparkSession.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], baseSchema)

Hope it helps you.